# How do I stop Delphi from freeing TArray<T>'s memory?

Tags: delphi

In delphi :

```pascal
procedure test();
var
  data: TArray<SomeClass>;
begin
  SetLength(data, 10);
end; // data is freed
```

How can I prevent `data` from being freed here ? In my actual code, I'm passing its values to the caller so they must be kept in-memory. The array object can be freed, but not its contents.

Note : I know that I should make a container object to keep the data alive and in sync as long as needed ; I can't rework the thousands of lines of bad code around this however.

Comment: Dynamic arrays are reference counted, so you never need to think about them. Object are reference types that you explicitly create and destroy, so that's not a problem either. Your Q therefore makes no sense at all.

Comment: In your case `data` is a local variable therefore it will be always freed when code goes out of the scope of your procedure. This is how local variables work. Quick and dirty approach of how to avoid this is to declare your `data` variable outside of your procedure and pass it to your procedure as variable parameter. But you should seriously consider refactoring of those thousand lines of bad code. Sure it will take a lot of work today. But how about next month or next year when you have even more code that is dependant on this and you are forced into refactoring?

Comment: "In my actual code, I'm passing its values to the caller" show us a better approximation of your actual code then.

Comment: Your approach sounds as if you want to increase the lines of bad code surrounding this routine. You might want to elaborate on your particular situation to find a good and sustainable solution. If you do - please edit your question with further details

Answer (score 2):

A [*dynamic array*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) is a compiler-managed reference type.  It has an internal reference counter and will be freed automatically when that counter falls to 0, such as when your local variable goes out of scope.

Note that you stated:

> The array object can be freed, but not its contents.

That is exactly what happens in your example.  You are declaring an array of objects. The compiler will free only the array itself, not the objects, as class types are also reference types (but not reference counted), and thus will not be freed automatically by the compiler.  Only compiler-managed types (strings, interfaces, records, and dynamic arrays) will be freed automatically when the dynamic array is freed.

---

Now, that being said, if for some reason you still want to avoid the array data from being freed when it goes out of scope, then you have 2 choices:

- don't use a dynamic array to begin with.  Use [`GetMem()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.GetMem) or [`AllocMem()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AllocMem) or [`New()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.New) instead to manually allocate a block of memory to hold the data.  The caller will be responsible for freeing this memory properly (or passing it back to you so you can free it).

```
type
  PSomeClass = ^SomeClass;

var
  dataPtr: PSomeClass;

GetMem(dataPtr, SizeOf(SomeClass) * 10);
...
// use dataPtr as needed...
...
FreeMem(dataPtr);
```

- Manually reset the local variable's data pointer to `nil` before it goes out of scope.  Dynamic arrays are implemented as a pointer to a control block containing the array's data and reference counter.  Setting this pointer to `nil` will force the variable to lose access to its control block, thus the reference counter won't be updated when the variable goes out of scope.  The memory will remain allocated.  To free the memory, the caller (or you) will then have to manually re-assign that pointer back into another dynamic array variable, or otherwise call [`System.DynArrayClear()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DynArrayClear) directly.

```
type
  PSomeClass = ^SomeClass;

var
  data: TArray<SomeClass>;
  dataPtr: PSomeClass;

SetLength(data, 10);
dataPtr := PSomeClass(data);
Pointer(data) := nil; // disengage the refcount!
...
// use dataPtr as needed...
...
Pointer(data) := dataPtr; // reengage the refcount!
// let data go out of scope...
```

Comment: Won't the reference count of the array be decreased when you re-assign it a new value? And thus, the Array part of the variable will be released (just as it does when it goes out of scope).

Comment: Yes, that's how reference counting works. But nowhere in my answer did I suggest reassigning a new value to the array.

Comment: What do you mean by "Manually reset the local variable's data pointer to nil before it goes out of scope" then? I take it as you assigning NIL to "data" (ie. "data:=NIL") and in that case, the array will be de-allocated...

Comment: I updated my answer with examples of what I described

Comment: Okay - that wasn't clear (at least not to me).